# js not writing whole variable, stopping at hyphen in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, variables, document.write

My script was working fine last night, and this morning it is not completing the whole variable path. For both href links and image src tags, it stopped at the -. For example, the image page was "/iwov-resources/images/image.jpg" and it wrote "/iwov".

This is not happening in chrome, only IE. I did get around this by updating my paths to have no hyphens, but that is a band aid.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

here is my code:

```
   function loadSlice() {

  var path = '/templatedata/local/OpcoSliceTeaser/data/SliceTeaser.xml';
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }
    else
      {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

    xmlhttp.open("GET",path,false);
    xmlhttp.send();


      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

      {

            var colHead;
            var header;
            var headertext;
            var colText;
            var imgPath;
            var myImg;
            var imgAlt;
            var myAlt;
            var headline;
            var myHeadline;
            var teaser;
            var teaserText;
          var moreText;
          var myMoreText;
          var moreLink;
          var myMoreLink;


            colHead=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("imagecontainer");
            colText=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Textcontainer");



        for (var i=0;i<colHead.length;i++)
             {
                header=colHead[i].getElementsByTagName("HeaderText");
                headertext =  header[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                moreText =colHead[i].getElementsByTagName("MoreText");
                myMoreText =  moreText[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                moreLink =colHead[i].getElementsByTagName("MoreLinkURL");
                myMoreLink =  moreLink[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
             }

          for (var i=0;i<colText.length;i++)
             {
                imgPath=colText[i].getElementsByTagName("ImgPath");
                myImg =  imgPath[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                imgAlt= colText[i].getElementsByTagName("ImgAltText");
                myAlt =  imgAlt[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                headline = colText[i].getElementsByTagName("HeadlineText");
                myHeadline =  headline[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                teaser = colText[i].getElementsByTagName("TeaserText");
                teaserText =  teaser[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
             }




        var navtxt;
         navtxt = '<div class="subHeadline_wrapper"><h4><a target="" href="' + myMoreLink + '">';
          navtxt = navtxt +  headertext;
          navtxt = navtxt + "</a></h4></div>";
          navtxt = navtxt + '<div class="image_wrapper center"><a target="" href="' + myMoreLink + '">' + '<img src="' + myImg + '" border="0" alt="' + myAlt + '"/></a></div>';
          navtxt = navtxt + '<div class="container"><div class="headline_wrapper"><h3><a target="" href="' + myMoreLink + '">' + myHeadline + '</a></h3></div>';

          navtxt = navtxt + '<div class="text_wrapper">' + teaserText + '</div></div>';

           navtxt = navtxt + '<div class="more-link-wrapper"><a target="_self" href="' + myMoreLink + '"><span>' + myMoreText + '</span></a></div>';



        document.getElementById("APCslice").innerHTML = navtxt ;


        }


      }
```

Here is my xml that passes fine:

```
<root>
<imagecontainer>
<Style>Mini Col</Style>
<HeaderText>POWER</HeaderText>
<Textcontainer>
<ImgPath>/images/Security_Series_APCSlice.jpg</ImgPath>
<ImgAltText>Security team has extensive industry experience</ImgAltText>
<HeadlineText>Security team has extensive industry experience</HeadlineText>
<TeaserText>
<p>Powerlines today introduces &ldquo;The 101&rdquo; series, providing a general overview of company departments, such as Security, Hydro and Distribution.</p>
</TeaserText>
</Textcontainer>
<MoreText>More Powerlines</MoreText>
<MoreLinkURL>http://sotoday.southernco.com/apc/</MoreLinkURL>
</imagecontainer>
<Vpath/>
</root>
```

But if my image path, or links is :

```
 <ImgPath>/images/Security-Series-APCSlice.jpg</ImgPath>
```

it only writes "/images/Security"

Also if anyone has any tips on how to maybe simplify this to make it faster that would be mighty helpful as well, thanks all!

Comment: Can you try `myImg =  imgPath[0].textContent;` instead, and see if that changes things?

Comment: I suspect IE might be splitting the element content into several text nodes at the hyphen, so that there is more than one - but since you only get the content of the first one, the rest is missing. So you could also try and call `imgPath[0].normalize()` first, to force the browser to consolidate it back into a single one.

Comment: @CBroe ill give it a shot! thanks!